# Getting error in partition of array for QuickSort

Tags: java, quicksort, indexoutofboundsexception

I am trying to partition an array as per the Quick Sort algorithm but getting weird output while trying to do so. Below is the code.

Input Array

```
 int[] newArray = {24, 26, 8, 6, 14, 33, 21, 19};
 partitionArray(newArray, -1, newArray.length - 1);
```

Partition Method

```
private static int partitionArray(int[] array, int leftPointer, int rightPointer) {

  int pivot = rightPointer;
  while (leftPointer < rightPointer) {

      System.out.println("leftPointer: " + leftPointer + " rightPointer: " + rightPointer);

      while (array[++leftPointer] <= array[pivot] && leftPointer < rightPointer);
      while (array[--rightPointer] > array[pivot] && rightPointer > leftPointer);

      System.out.println("leftPointer2: " + leftPointer + " rightPointer2: " + rightPointer);

      if (leftPointer < rightPointer) {
          swapElements(array, leftPointer, rightPointer);
      }
  }
    swapElements(array, leftPointer, pivot);
    return leftPointer;
}
```

Output :

```
  leftPointer: -1 rightPointer: 7
  leftPointer2: 0 rightPointer2: 4
  leftPointer: 0 rightPointer: 4
  leftPointer2: 1 rightPointer2: 3
  leftPointer: 1 rightPointer: 3
  leftPointer2: 3 rightPointer2: 2
  leftPointer: -2 rightPointer: 3
  Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: -1
```

Once `leftPointer > rightPointer` it should not enter while, but it does. And how these values are set to `-2` and `3`.

Comment: @lared nope that is not it, tried still got the error

Comment: Whoops, sorry. You're right. Anyway - can't reproduce. Using your code and the very same data the algorithm terminates correctly after `leftPointer2: 3 rightPointer2: 2`